# Calcular una rotación en quaternion?

Tags: c++, c++11, ogre

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un cuerpo rígido (Bullet) relacionado a un nodo (Ogre), la idea es rotar el cuerpo rígido para que rote el nodo, el problema es que no tiene las funciones yaw(), pitch(), roll() o rotate(), entonces solamente puedo asignar un Queaternion, ->setQuaternion, la pregunta es la siguiente:

Como aplico (mediante cálculos) una rotación en yaw, en pitch y el roll a un quaternion:

La idea es mas o menos la siguiente:

```
Ogre::Quaternion actual = _rigidBox->getOrientation();
actual = calcularYaw(actual);
_rigidBox->setQuaternion(actual);
```

Como implemento la función calcularYaw? puedo pasar Degree o Radian (da igual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de nada: no he usado *Ogre*, así que esto es *teórico*. No obstante, dada la fuente, *debería* funcionar.

En la Wiki de Ogre tienes un apartado en exclusiva para las rotaciones con cuaterniones:

[Quaternion and Rotation Primer](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Quaternion%20and%20Rotation%20Primer)

Copio y pego uno de sus párrafos:

> Like matrices, we can combine quaternion rotations by multiplying them. However they are still not commutative. Q1 * Q2 != Q2 * Q1. Thus the order of application is still important.

En traducción *muy libre* por mi parte:

> Como con las matrices, se pueden combinar las rotaciones usando cuaterniones simplemente multiplicandolas entre si. Ten en cuenta que dicha operación **no es conmutativa**: `Q1 * Q2 != Q2 * Q1`. El orden **es** importante.

Un poco mas abajo tenemos un ejemplo de como aplicar una rotación de 90º al eje X; aplicado a tu código, quedaría:

```
Ogre::Quaternion actual( _rigidBox->getOrientation( ) );

_rigidBox->setQuaternion( actual * Ogre::Quaternion( Ogre::Degree( 90 ), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X ) );
```

Recuerdo, de cuando me toco *lidiar* con cuaterniones (hace bastantes años) que, para aplicar una rotación a mas de un eje a la vez, se hacía algo así como aplicar **un porcentaje** en cada eje. No estoy demasiado seguro, pero quedaría algo como esto:

```
_rigidBox->setQuaternion( actual * Ogre::Quaternion( Ogre::Degree( 360 ), 1 / ROTX, 1 / ROTY, 1 / ROTZ ) );
```

Es decir, aplicamos el **maximo** grado posible de rotación (360º), y, para cada eje, tomamos solo la cantiad necesaria. Si quieres rotar X e Y 180º, y dejar Z intacto, sería algo como:

```
_rigidBox->setQuaternion( actual * Ogre::Quaternion( Ogre::Degree( 360 ), 0.5, 0.5, 0 ) );
```

Lamento no poder ser mas exacto, pero repito que fue hace bastante tiempo.

Comment: Recuerdo que, cuando me tocó a mi, tarde **2 días** en comprender como se hacía. Lástima que no conserve el código de aquellos *experimentos* :-(

Comment: Me da error la parte "Vector::UNIT_X". Estoy intentando, espero que funcione

Comment: Huy, falta el `namespace`. Prueba con `Ogre::Vector::UNIT_X`.

Comment: Y el nombre de la clase está mal. No, si resulta que no se hacer ni un *copy/paste* en condiciones :-O `Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X`.

Comment: No me ha funcionado bien :(

Comment: [¿chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) A ver que si lo echamos a andar O_o